# I am getting IIS7 Default page

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I have a web aplication on iis7 which is reachable from the web. When I write ip adres like this 95.X.X.X:8888 it returns İİS7 default image. But when i type 95.X.X.X:8888/mypage it gives the login page successfully.

I checked the Default pages on iis. There was no problem. The Login.aspx page is on the list.

What might be the problem?

Comment: My application is under the Default Web site. The web.config on the default site has this code: htttpRedirect="true" destination="/mypage" . Why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the `httpRedirect="false"` to `httpRedirect="true"` it worked.